# Mixed Standard C Code

Tags: c, coding-style

I'm working on a project that is suppose to be cross platform. Since I'd like it to be easy to work with in windows environments, I decided to support the Microsoft C compiler. This means that most code will have to be adhere to the oldest C standard.

I'm wondering if it would be good idea to use a higher C standard in the sources containing implementations for unix environments and use the lowest standard in the base sources and windows sources. This way I could give a little bit more freedom to the sources that wouldn't ever be compiled with the Microsoft compiler.

Here's an illustration:

```
# uses -pedantic
src/file1.c
src/file2.c

# uses -pedantic
src/windows/file3.c
src/windows/file4.c

# may use -std=c99 or -std=gnu99
src/unix/file5.c
src/unix/file6.c
```

But, would this be a violation of style consistency?

It would heavily impact the placement of variables within a function. On unix sources, most variables will be declared where they are first needed. On base and window sources, they would all have to be placed at the top of the function.

Comment: Just don't use the oldish compiler that doesn't implement C99. Even on windows there are alternatives that are standard conforming.

Comment: That's what I've thought. But I'm just hesitant, because I've seen a few projects that seem to think that older compiler support is important (git, libgit, freetype, libuv, others).

Comment: Don't bother unless having your code compile on ancient and obscure compilers is really important to you. It's a trade-off like everything. Heck, some projects (e.g., Vim and Readline) still use pre-ANSI C function declarations. You can run GCC (via MinGW for example) on Windows.